Images are not displayed in Angular 18
I have started to learn Angular 18 framework and there is a problem that when I launch the site, images are not displayed. There are no problems in the code, even when loading a finished project from the official Angular documentation still do not display images. Instead of them there is an "alt" text
Has anyone experienced this problem yet?

Can you share some code ?

I have faced the same problem while creating new project with Angular 18.
I solve the issue like this.
Put the all images assets in /public/assets folder.
Then, you can use the image link like this
src="assets/image.png"

That works for me.
My development env was ubuntu 23.0.4, Node v21.14.0, Angular v18.
Hope my solution works for you.

public folder is in same path than src folder

In Angular 18, if you want to display an image, it's necessary to put it in the 'public' folder at the root project level (at the same level as src). The public folder is not default created. You have to create it manually.
view project folder structure
After that, you can access to the image file like this (note that it's necessary add . to the path) :
<img src="./assets/error.png">


Adding this to angular.json helped me:
"architect": { ...
               "assets": [
                               {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "public"
              },
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "src/assets",
                "output": "/assets"
              }]


I'm also new to angular (running version 18.0.1) and have the same problem.
I created a new app with ng new test.
Then I added an assets/images folder to src.
In angular.json, I added src/assets (tried also with src/assets/images) to the assets array
 "assets": [
              "src/assets",
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "public"
              }
            ],

main.ts
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { appConfig } from './app/app.config';
import { AppComponent } from './app/app.component';

bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, appConfig)
  .catch((err) => console.error(err));

app.component.ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterOutlet } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [RouterOutlet],
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrl: './app.component.css'
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'test';
}

app.component.html
When I press ctrl + left click on  ../assets/images/images.jpg it takes me to the image.
I tried also src="assets/images/images.jpg"/>
<h1>I'm here</h1>
<div>
  <img width=100 height="150" src="../assets/images/images.jpg"/>
  <h2>two</h2>
</div>

Image
Here's the look of the page

I'm sure you've already solved it, but it's without the ../ after declaring it on your angular.json file

I faced the same issue When I created a new app using angular 18, but it emitted the same error every time, thus I created a new app using angular17 and updated that to V18. now it works fine,
<img ngSrc="./assets/a.png"  alt="mission" height="636" width="640" >

happy cording...

"architect": { ...
               "assets": [
                               {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "public"
              },
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "src/assets",
                "output": "/assets"
              }] 

Using the code above and moving the assets folder to the public folder it should work
html will look like
<img src="assests/images/avatar.png" alt=''avatar">

You have to add "src/assets"  in your angular.json file.
like below code,
"assets": [
              "src/assets",
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "public"
              }
            ]


Convert the image to Base64 and use it. it will work.

instead of   src="/public/Image.png"   use directly   src="Image.png"   it will work.

I'm using Angular 18.2 and Node.js 22.9.0 in macOS Sequoia. I also had the same issue.
Solution 1
So, I created assets folder under the public folder generated from the app itself and kept all images inside of it. Then restarted the server by running ng serve and my issue was resolved.
Solution 2
In angular.json file replace this part:
"assets": [
          {
            "glob": "**/*",
            "input": "public"
          }
        ],

with this:
"assets": [
          "src/assets"
        ],

Both of the above solutions worked for me. I used the URL as assets/image-name.png.
